# Equation doesn't seem to fit one of the cross product properties

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, operator-theory, vector-analysis

One of the cross product properties I am referring too is the following
$$A \times (B \times C)= B(A \cdot C) - C(A \cdot B)$$

Now consider this identity:

$$V( \nabla \cdot V)= \nabla(V^2/2) - V \times \omega$$

Where $\omega=(\nabla \times V)$

$V$ is vector and $\nabla$ is the gradient.
I don't understand this identity since the left hand side is not divided by $2$.

I have written as Letting $A=\nabla$ $B=\nabla$ and $C=V$ I can rewrite as
$V \times ( \nabla \times V)= \nabla(V \cdot V) - V(\nabla \cdot  V)$

Update: I just found the property being used and I am not even sure how to prove it.

$\nabla( V \cdot V)= V( \nabla \cdot V) + (V \cdot \nabla)V + V\times (\nabla \times V) +V \times (\nabla \times V)     $

This explains where the one half is coming from but how to prove this is a mystery

Comment: @ Caution: identities involving the cross product typically don't work if some of the vectors are differential operators (unless you make suitable changes), because their proofs rely on commutators being zero. For example $V\cdot\nabla\times V$ isn't always zero.

Comment: How Is $\nabla (V^2/2)$ evaluated?

Comment: It's the vector whose $i$th component is $\partial_i \left( V^2/2\right) = V\partial_i V$, so the final result is $V\nabla V$.

Comment: @J.G So it looks like we are going to have for the I component $u \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}$ for j is $v \frac{\partial V}{\partial y}$ and for $k$ is $w \frac{\partial V}{\partial z}$ right?

Comment: Sorry; I forgot $V$ is a vector. We have $\partial_i V^2/2 = \partial_i \sum_j V_j^2/2 = \sum_j V_j \partial_i V_j = V\cdot\partial_i V_j$. Then we make a vector out of that, giving something one is tempted to denote $V\cdot\nabla V$, though that's not standard notation. It's best to prove the desired result by writing its ith component as a scalar equation, then proving that.

Comment: @J.G. $u \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + u \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} + u \dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}$ is the scalar equation for the ith component then from your notation?

Comment: Yes; that's the first component, if $x=x_1$. For others, replace $\partial_x$ with $\partial_y$ etc.